# Scanning for BLE devices on Android 8+ in the background

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble, bluetooth-gatt

I'm using the following method from BLE scanner API on Android 8+
to scan for BLE Beacons

```
startScan(List<ScanFilter> filters, ScanSettings settings, 
PendingIntent callbackIntent)
```

The problem is that after sometimes I can see Scan Logs but nothing is delivered by the `callbackIntent` any idea why is this happening?

Comment: use https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle for get better result

Comment: There's also https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library for this specific use case

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior on Android 8+. if you need to scan continuously a periodic mechanism is needed in this case. For more information about scanning on different Android versions and different ways. Have a look [here](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8)

Comment: Well if you have a Foreground Service the restrictions you link to do not apply anymore.

Comment: As I said it is for background scanning. Not all use cases require a foreground service which was our case.